# Laravel Livewire 2.x is event on table row click

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have very simple Table in Laravel Livewire

```
<table class="table-auto w-full">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="px-4 py-2">Id</th>
            <th class="px-4 py-2">Name</th>
            <th class="px-4 py-2">Age</th>
            <th class="px-4 py-2">Action</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($students as $student)
            <tr>
                <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{$student->id}}</td>
                <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{$student->name}}</td>
                <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{$student->age}}</td>
                <td class="border px-4 py-2">
                    <x-jet-danger-button wire:click="confirmItemDeletion( {{ $student->id}})" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
                        Delete
                    </x-jet-danger-button>
                </td>
            <tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Delete button is also working.
I want to open another model for edit on row click while delete button should be working too.

I try to add this code in every  but its working but

```
<td class="border px-4 py-2" wire:click="confirmItemEdit( {{ $item->id}})">{{$student->id}}</td>
```

1. not showing link cursor. to get this I put this style in `<tr style="cursor: pointer;">`
2. also is there a way to not to write wire:click in every

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're using Tailwindcss, so you can use `cursor-pointer` on your `<tr>` element;

```
<tr class="cursor-pointer">
...
</tr>
```

You can chek out the other [cursor classes available here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/cursor).

2. You should be able to wire the click event to your `<tr>` element;

```
<tr wire:click="confirmItemEdit({{ $item->id }})">
...
</td>
```

**Update**

So when you put a `click` handler on the entire `<tr>` and another on a button, both `click` events fire, the button event first and then the row.

Top avoid this, use the `.stop` modifier on the button `click` event.

```
<tr class="cursor-pointer" wire:click="confirmItemEdit({{ $item->id }})">
  <td>...</td>
  <td>
    <button wire:click.stop="confirmItemDeletion({{ $student->id }})">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The `.stop` modifier prevents the `click` event propagating. More information on [event modifiers here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions#event-modifiers).

Comment: Thanks but the problem is if I put it in <tr> then my delete button stop working

Comment: thx for all help but its not working, I even put class="z-999" but not working

Comment: @Mr.SH You're right, I have updated my answer.